# is it possible to divide a set in multiple dense sets

Tags: real-analysis

lets say i have a non empty set $A$, and lets say i have $n$ sets $A_i$ where:

- every set $A_i$ is dense in $A$
- $\displaystyle\bigcup_iA_i = A$
- $i\ne j;A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$

is it possible to such partition exist for all number greater than 1? if it not alway possible, what is the condition to it exist?

Comment: What do you mean by "dense"?

Comment: this depends on the topology of $A$, by example in the trivial topology $\{\emptyset,A\}$ this would work for any partition of $A$, however in the discrete topology this cannot be done for any $n\ge 2$

Comment: Is $A$ a set of real numbers? If not, what does "dense" mean?

Comment: It's certainly not possible if $A$ is a finite set.

Comment: The question, as asked, has been answered below assuming $A=\mathbb{R}$. Perhaps a more interesting question, with basically the same idea in mind, is characterizing infinite topological spaces $X$ with cardinality $\kappa$ with the property that they are the disjoint union of $\kappa$ pairwise disjoint dense sets. In other words, which topological spaces can be "maximally split" into dense sets?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvable_space

Answer (score 3):

The see of rationals and the set of irrationals are both dense in $\mathbb  R$, they are disjoint and their union is $\mathbb  R$.

Comment: To expand on this, by 'shifting' the rationals by irrationals (for example, $\mathbb{Q} + \pi$), one could split $\mathbb{R}$ in *at least* a countable infinity of dense sets.

Comment: Indeed, @AlexanderGeldhof, one might as well take a linear basis $\mathcal B$ of $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$, uncountable in number, and shift $\Bbb Q$ by every element of $\mathcal B$.